# how do you download 2D-extras in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am making a game in Unity 2019.1 and I do not know how to download 2D extras into unity. let alone I do not understand how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Unity techdemos 2d extras is a repository by unity  having some scripts to add additional functionality on a 2d basis. To download 2d extras go to the link https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/2d-extras and download the repo. After extracting it in your project, you can easily add scripts available there on the game objects and simply avail various tilemap brushes.

@Bonnie49er1